# Replace string containing parantheses

Tags: r

I have a vector that looks like this:

```
vector <- c("SPN.subset(RELN).geneset1", "Myeloid.svz.geneset1")
```

I want to replace `"SPN.subset(RELN).geneset1"` with `"SPN.subset(RELN).caudate.geneset1"`, but it seems the parantheses aren't allowing this to happen:

e.g

```
> gsub("SPN.subset(RELN).geneset1", "SPN.subset(RELN).caudate.geneset1", vector)
[1] "SPN.subset(RELN).geneset1" "Myeloid.svz.geneset1"
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

We could escape the special characters with `\\` in the pattern of `gsub`:
Notice akrun is providing a more general approach!

```
gsub("SPN.subset\\(RELN\\).geneset1", "SPN.subset(RELN).caudate.geneset1", vector)
```

```
[1] "SPN.subset(RELN).caudate.geneset1" "Myeloid.svz.geneset1"
```

Comment: Instead of that, you can use `fixed = TRUE` as well

Answer (score 2):

We may match the closing parentheses, followed by the `.`, andi. nthe replacement, add the `).` followed by the `caudate` substring

```
sub("\\)\\.", ").caudate.", vector)
[1] "SPN.subset(RELN).caudate.geneset1" "Myeloid.svz.geneset1"
```

---

with `gsub/sub`, the default option is `fixed = FALSE` i.e. in regex mode.  When it is in regex mode, the `()` is treated differently i.e. it is a metacharacter to capture group instead of literally evaluating